# Updating a view column in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

So, I have a database of customers information ranging from phone numbers to names and even location.

I created a view of only the active customers and included an extra blank column where we can indicate if the customer has made purchase or not.

The issue now is, i keep getting an error: **cannot update column "buy" of view**

I tried entering a value in the blank column created.

Please how can I update a blank column in view

Comment: Can you share your VIEW ?

Comment: What is a blank column in a view? You can't store data in a view, that can only be done in a table. What table should store this data and does this table have a column like this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a view column defined like

```
NULL::text AS viewvol
```

or

```
''::text AS viewcol
```

you cannot insert values into that column, nor can you update it. Data modifications on a view are translated to data modifications on the base table, and that only works for view columns that are defined using table columns.

What you can and should do is to create an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger for the view that performs the desired operation on the base table.